# How to fix the warning about building Firebase with CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to iOS development and need your help. 
I got some warnings when I built Firebase/Firestore installed by `Xcode13` | `CocoaPods`.

One of them is this.
I am getting this warning.
`Anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here`.

The location is `/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h`

```h
typedef struct {
  grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
  size_t size = 0;
} grpc_credentials_mdelem_array;
```

I got a suggestion for a fix through research.

1. To add `inhibit_all_warnings!` to the Podfile.
   It was very simple to remove the warnings.
   But I don't understand. Can I ignore the warnings I'm getting?
   Isn't that the essential solution?
2. Modify the structure declaration.
   I was able to get rid of the warning by modifying it as described below.
   However, in order to fix it, we have to unlock the file.
   Is this a file I am allowed to touch?

The fix went like this.

```h
struct grpc_credentials_mdelem_array {
  grpc_mdelem* md = nullptr;
  size_t size = 0;
};
```

What action should I take to solve this problem?
1 or 2 or something else?